ZPL Incremental alphanumeric
Today I have a command to print some label using an incremental numeric SN like you can see below.
^XA
^FWR^FS
^BY3,
^LH00,00
^BY100,100^FT290,120^BXN,8,200,0,0,1,^SN1339708704,4^FS
^FO070,40^A0N,50,40^SN1389708704,4^FS
^BY100,100^FT730,120^BXN,8,200,0,0,1,^SN1339708705,4^FS
^FO510,40^A0N,50,40^SN1389708705,4^FS
^BY100,100^FT1160,120^BXN,8,200,0,0,1,^SN1339708706,4^FS
^FO930,40^A0N,50,40^SN1389708706,4^FS
^BY100,100^FT1600,120^BXN,8,200,0,0,1,^SN1339708707,4^FS
^FO1380,40^A0N,50,40^SN1389708707,4^FS
^PQ2
^XZ

Now I will need to change this SN for a alphanumeric code, but this incremental part of code will be just the 4 intermediary characters.
The future the code will be like this below:
^XA
^FWR^FS
^BY3,
^LH00,00
^BY100,100^FT290,120^BXN,8,200,0,0,1,^SN1330001H7E,4^FS
^FO070,40^A0N,50,40^SN1380001H7E,4^FS
^BY100,100^FT730,120^BXN,8,200,0,0,1,^SN1330002H7E,4^FS
^FO510,40^A0N,50,40^SN1380002H7E,4^FS
^BY100,100^FT1160,120^BXN,8,200,0,0,1,^SN1330003H7E,4^FS
^FO930,40^A0N,50,40^SN1380003H7E,4^FS
^BY100,100^FT1600,120^BXN,8,200,0,0,1,^SN1330004H7E,4^FS
^FO1380,40^A0N,50,40^SN1380004H7E,4^FS
^PQ2
^XZ

For example:
133 - are a fix code
0001 - is an incremental alphanumeric code(34 base)
H7E - will be a date identification
I think that now I will need to separate all information and concatenated when I will do the ZPL label information.
I would like to know if has someone command for increment an alphanumeric code by ZPL?

What language are you using to generate the ZPL?  It should be easy to modify.

^SN is documented to support alphanumeric codes, it's just that it will increment the rightmost number block, in your case the 7 in H7E. You are requesting increment by 4, so the next value will be 11, which will be truncated to 1 because there is only one digit space.

You need to write additional software exporting the correct ZPL code to achieve this goal. ZPL alone is only a markup language and can't solve programming tasks like string concatenation.
